# matplotlib how to display axis values as strings not a range of floats

Tags: python, matplotlib

I wrote the following script to plot the frequencies of items in a python list. When the list is of strings, I am not able to display the actual string values on the x axis and I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testy.py", line 15, in <module>
    plt.bar([row[0] for row in votes_count], [row[1] for row in votes_count])
  File "...\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2705, in bar
    **kwargs)
  File "....\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1891, in inner
    return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
  File "....\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 2105, in bar
    left = [left[i] - width[i] / 2. for i in xrange(len(left))]
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float'
```

Here is the code:

```
from collections import Counter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import plotly.plotly as py #pip install plotly 

votes = ['a','a','b','c','d']
tmp_votes_count = Counter (votes)
votes_count = []

for i in tmp_votes_count:
    votes_count.append ([i, tmp_votes_count[i]])


margin = 2
most_common_vote= [item for item in Counter(votes).most_common(1)]
plt.bar([row[0] for row in votes_count], [row[1] for row in votes_count])
plt.axis([0,4,0,most_common_vote[0][1]+margin])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please note `matplotlib.pyploy.bar()` will only accept sequence of scalars as arguments. **[Check Reference](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=bar#matplotlib.pyplot.bar)**

Answer (score 2):

You firstly need to define axis as integers

```
plt.bar(range(0, len(votes_count)), [row[1] for row in votes_count])
```

and then map them to actual `str` objects

```
plt.xticks(range(0, len(votes_count)), [row[0] for row in votes_count])
```

Finally, 3 last refactored lines:

```
plt.bar(range(0, len(votes_count)), [row[1] for row in votes_count])
plt.xticks(range(0, len(votes_count)), [row[0] for row in votes_count])
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: I tried it and got the columns not in the correct order (a, c, b, d) is there a way to fix the order?

Comment: @A_Matar the order could be change in you change the `votes` list. The order would be order how letters occur in your list